# PHP SQL Discount Code For Specific Items?

Tags: php, sql, database, function

This function successfully calculates a global percentage using a single discount code, although I'm having problems making the code discount a specific range of items instead of globally.   The basket session holds id, name, desc, price, qty etc... but everything I've tried thus far has failed, I realize I need to implement it into the foreach loop (which I keep breaking or updates every item one way or another) or use a different method entirely but I'm really unsure as how to proceed.

I'm not an experienced PHP Dev by the way I just enjoy learning and working basic markup.  Any helpful pointers someone can provide would be very much appreciated.  Thanks!

```
    $code = $this->request['code'];

    $discount_status = 'NONE'; // no discount available / applied
    if ( !empty($this->config['DISCOUNT_CODE']) && !empty($this->config['DISCOUNT_PERCENT']) && !empty($code) ) {
        if ( $code == $this->config['DISCOUNT_CODE'] ) {
            $discount_status = 'OK';
        }
        else {
            $discount_status = 'ERROR';
        }
    }       

    // calculate basket total
    $basket_value = 0;
    $discount_factor = 1;
    if ( $discount_status == 'OK' ) {
        // apply discount
        $discount_factor = ( 100 - $this->config['DISCOUNT_PERCENT'] ) / 100;
    }   

    if ( !empty($_SESSION['basket']) && is_array($_SESSION['basket']) ) {       
    foreach( $_SESSION['basket'] as $basketItem ) {                 
        // Apply discount to each item separately       
        $basket_value += sprintf("%.02f", $basketItem['detail_price'] * $discount_factor) * $basketItem['qty'];  
        }       
    }   

    // check delivery cost
    $delivery_area = $this->DeliveryAreaManager->getRecord($this->request['da']);
    if ( !empty($delivery_area['cost']) && ( $delivery_area['free_from'] <= 0 || $basket_value < $delivery_area['free_from'] ) ) {
        $basket_value += $delivery_area['cost'];
    }

    // return JSON response
    $data = JSONUtils::encode(
        array(
            'discount_status' => $discount_status,
            'basket_value' => sprintf("%.02f", $basket_value),
        )
    );

    return $data;
```

Comment: You took the time to write all this, but you didn't take the time to ask a question.

Comment: I thought the question was clear, what is the best way to call the desired items and apply a discount to only them, I've called the items directly from SQL but I do not know how to make the foreach loop only update the pre-selected items, as I said it keeps updating globally.  The items don't change, the question being how to I update these pre-selected items rather than all items in the shopping basket.

Comment: first question: Why applying the discount to each item separately? Secondly: How do I know which items are "good for discount"? what is the condition?

Comment: what exactly you needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
foreach( $_SESSION['basket'] as $basketItem ) {                 
    // Apply discount to each item separately       
    $basket_value += sprintf("%.02f", $basketItem['detail_price'] * $discount_factor) * $basketItem['qty'];      
}
```

Is saying to apply the discount to each item. It has no conditions. You would need to define the conditions that tell the code what to apply the discount to. This is extremely broad so we CAN'T tell you how to do this for YOU, but we CAN tell you how you MIGHT do it in a very horribly generic way...

```
foreach( $_SESSION['basket'] as $basketItem ) {                 
    // Apply discount to each item separately
    if($basketItem['discount_bracket'] == 1)
    {
        $basket_value += sprintf("%.02f", $basketItem['detail_price'] * $discount_factor) * $basketItem['qty'];  
    }
    else
    {
        $basket_value += sprintf("%.02f", $basketItem['detail_price']) * $basketItem['qty'];
    }
}
```

Now, obviously I just made up $basketItem['discount_bracket'] to tell you that you can make discount tiers or some kind of discount identifier for an item via the database. In this case, I just use it to say if 1 then the item can be discounted. It's up to you to make this do what you want it to do with what you have available. Seeing as we don't know what you can do or what you have available, we are limited in what we can suggest.

This is just one way to handle things. If you narrow down your question I might update with a more specific example.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, I'd been going about it the whole wrong way.  Thank you for taking the time to educate me, saved a lot of head scratching :D